# Calling a function from the base class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have class A and B.

```
class A{
public:
    foo();
};

class B : public A{
public:
    int x;
};
```

Assume that there is an object from B class in a test file.How should I call foo function?

```
object.foo(); // or
object.A::foo();
```

Other questions:
When do we call a function like that?What if I do multiple inheritance?

Comment: What problem are you having? This is really basic and you should simply try it. Not to mention read [your C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)...

Comment: I would highly encourage you to go to the last link I added in my answer about Difference between `private, public and protected inheritance in C++`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class B inherits public members of class A, so function `foo()` also belongs to class B and can be called using B class's object.

```
B b;
b.foo();
```

You need to know [inheritance in c++.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_inheritance.htm) Its just same as

```
b.x;
```

See `x` and `foo()` both are member of object `b` even `b` is object of Class B and its possible because Class B inheritance features from Class A, In your code function `foo()`.

**Note** Class A has only one member function foo()

```
A a;
a.foo();
```

Is valid, But

```
a.x;
```

Is not valid

**EDIT:**  Multi-level inheritance   Class C inherits Class B and Class B inherits Class A, then

```
class C : public B{
public:
    int y;  
};

C c;
c.foo();  // correct
```

Is also valid.

And

```
c.x;
c.y;
```

Also valid, `x`, `y`, `foo()` all are member of Class C.

Notice: What I told you is multi-level [Multiple inheritance in C++](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/cplr134.htm) is different. Also three access specifiers in C++ are very important in case of inheritance: [public private protected in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

Simply `object.foo()`, and there's not much more to add:

```
B object;
object.foo();
```